# Find nothing but still run through if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a sub for my excel table, the macro read open another workbook then find a certain value (lz) of a column, read all relevant information, then proceed to find the next row with the same column value lz and do the same thing until its found result is the same as the first found result. That is when I know I have read all information from that certain lz and can jump to the next lz

So I tried this code so far:

```
        Set foundCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New1").Range("F:F").Find(What:=lz, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, After:=Range("F10000"), _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=False, MatchCase:=False)
            
        
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            firstFound = foundCell.Address
            Do
                'do something with the relevant data
                Set foundCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New1").Range("F:F").FindNext(foundCell)
            Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing And firstFound <> foundCell.Address
        Else
            flag = False
        End If
```

It works for about 2 loops then when it comes to a specific lz, it crash and the error is : "object variable or with block variable not set". When I try to debug to see where the problem is, i found out that at the last step before it crashed, the foundCell is Nothing but somehow it still goes through the big If at the beginning and make the error. I expect it to go to the else statement down below when this happens

Comment: Please add actual data to actual cell ranges so we can try it out.

Comment: Which line does it crash on ?

Comment: @TomBrunberg i dont think i can share the data because the its related to company privacy

Comment: @CDP1802 the code gives error on the line Set foundCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New1").Range("F:F").FindNext(foundCell). I found out that in the do something part, I jump to another workbook to write the data then comeback to the searching workbook with Workbooks(xxx).Activate but it probably breaks the code somehow

Comment: Nobody is asking you to reveal private or otherwise sensitive data. But it should not be too difficult to provide invented data that reproduces the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Typical VBA pitfall: When `foundCell` is `Nothing` (because nothing is found), your condition to stop the While-Loop is fulfilled, but VBA will check the second part of that condition anyhow, and as `foundCell` is Nothing, you will get a runtime error for the `foundCell.Address`-part of the statement.

My suggestion: Jump out of the loop with an `Exit`-statement. There are other ways to handle that, but what is important is that you don't use the `foundCell.Address`-property when `foundCell` can be `Nothing`, and therefore you need two separate checks.

```
firstFound = foundCell.Address
Do
    'do something with the relevant data
    Set foundCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New1").Range("F:F").FindNext(foundCell)
    If foundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do

Loop While firstFound <> foundCell.Address
```

Comment: Within the Do Loop foundCell will never be Nothing since without further matches it will just find the first one again.

Comment: @FunThomas I think I found the problem. I jump to another workbook to write the data and then before I set the next foundCell, I activate the currently searched workbook again, but that did not work for some reason. The line: Set foundCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New1").Range("F:F").FindNext(foundCell) is where the foundCell suppose to give results but it found nothing and there goes the error.

Comment: Yeah, also a common problem with VBA/Excel. Don't use `ActiveWorkbook`. Assign the workbook to a workbook variable and use that.

Answer (score -1):

Just make the IF statement inside the loop

Comment: That would break the logic of the `firstfound` check.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).